# Django, MySQL, JSONField - Filtering Issue with JSON Data

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-filter, django-jsonfield

I'm encountering an issue with filtering JSON data stored in a Django JSONField. While attempting to filter data using the icontains lookup, it seems to treat the JSON data as a string field, and the filtering doesn't work as expected. Here's a brief overview of my setup:

Model:

I have a Django model with a JSONField like this:

```py
from django.db import models

class ChatMessage(models.Model):
    template_message = models.JSONField(null=True)
```

The JSON data is stored in the following format in the database:

```py
{
    "header": {
        "type": "text",
        "content": "Hello"
    },
    "body": "Hi there",
    "footer": "Hello there"
}
```

Problem Description:

The problem I'm facing is with the filtering code. I want to filter objects based on values within the JSON data, but the icontains lookup seems to be treating it as a string field rather than a JSON field.

```py
ChatMessage.objects.filter(
    Q(template_message__header__content__icontains=search_key) |
    Q(template_message__body__icontains=search_key) |
    Q(template_message__footer__icontains=search_key)
)
```

Expected Outcome:

I expect the filtering to consider the JSON structure and filter based on the presence of `search_key` within any of the JSON values, such as in the content, body, or footer fields.

Error Messages:

I haven't received any error messages, but the filtering doesn't work as expected.

Comment: `ICONTAINS` is mapped to `ILIKE` SQL operator which is string one and obviously treates the argument as a string. You may try to use `contains` which is overrided for JSONField. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/queries/#contains Of course each property must be tested separately.

Comment: It's still not working as expected.`template_message__contains={"body": search_key}` this is the key which i am using for contains filtering

Comment: I recommend you to enable General Log on MySQL server temporarily and look at SQL text which is receiving by the server from your code. This may help to adjust your code.

Comment: Here is data from database:

`ChatMessage.objects.filter(id=156).first().template_message`
result: `'{"header": {"type": "text", "content": "header"}, "body": "body", "footer": "footer", "button": {"type": "url", "content": "https://www.google.com/"}}'`

type: string

I logged on to database and see that data is stored in correct format i mean json format.
Do i have to CAST data before filtering ?

Comment: [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.JSONField) is a special field and [containment and key lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/queries/#containment-and-key-lookups) is done in a special way on JSONField. This is why the docs points out that certain query methods were intentionally overridden for JSONField. See [Querying JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/queries/#querying-jsonfield)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `contains`/`icontains` to filter a `JSONField`'s value will not give you your desired result. To achieve your desired result, you can use `Substr` or `KT`(Django >= 4.2)

```py
from django.db.models import CharField, Q
from django.db.models.functions import Substr


ChatMessage.objects.annotate(
    header_content=Substr("template_message__header__content", 1, output_field=CharField()),
    body=Substr("template_message__body", 1, output_field=CharField()),
    footer=Substr("template_message__footer", 1, output_field=CharField()),
).filter(
    Q(header_content__icontains=search_key)
    | Q(body__icontains=search_key)
    | Q(footer__icontains=search_key)
)
```

If you are using Django >= 4.2, you can make use of `KT` as below

```py
from django.db.models.fields.json import KT
from django.db.models import Q


ChatMessage.objects.annotate(
    header_content=KT("template_message__header__content"),
    body=KT("template_message__body"),
    footer=KT("template_message__footer"),
).filter(
    Q(header_content__icontains=search_key)
    | Q(body__icontains=search_key)
    | Q(footer__icontains=search_key)
)
```